# IBM Cloud (Bluemix) unable to deploy error 502

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm trying to deploy an app on IBM Cloud (Bluemix) from a Github repository (https://github.com/IBM/watson-vehicle-damage-analyzer).

When I deploy the app I choose London as location. The project try to deploy but it stops with this error:

```
Server error, status code: 502, error code: 10001, message: Service broker error: No matching deployments for the given plan_id.
```

Can somebody explain me what this error means? I have a paid account on IBM Cloud.

Here is the full log of my error:

```
Preparing to start the job...
Preparing the build artifacts...
cf login -a "https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net" -u apikey -p "****" -o "xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com" -s "dev" 
API endpoint: https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net
Authenticating...
OK

Targeted org xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com

Targeted space dev



API endpoint:   https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net (API version: 2.106.0)
User:           gabriel.cuesta@mkdautomotive.com
Org:            gabriel.cuesta@mkdautomotive.com
Space:          dev
Creating service instance wvda-visual-recognition in org gabriel.cuesta@mkdautomotive.com / space dev as gabriel.cuesta@mkdautomotive.com...
FAILED
Server error, status code: 502, error code: 10001, message: Service broker error: No matching deployments for the given plan_id.

Finished: FAILED
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that in the `manifest.yml` file, it's creating a Watson VR service **lite** plan but as per the pricing on the website [here](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/watson-visual-recognition/pricing), Watson VR with the lite plan is available only in us-south (Dallas) region.

You can check the same here as well - https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/visual-recognition